# How can i get a variable from one controller and then pass the same variable to view

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers `ParentController` and `ChildController` I have a variable in ParentController and i need to get that variable to ChildController and then i need to pass it to the view and one more thing is i should not use the $scope in child controller and parentController. Is it possible ?if not is there any way to use it with out $scope.

```
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
    $scope.exampleVariable = "test";
});

app.controller('ChildController', function($scope, $controller) {
  var someScopeVariable = this;
  $controller('ParentController', {$scope: someScopeVariable });
  console.log(someScopeVariable.exampleVariable) 
  someScopeVariable.exampleVariable = "Updatetest";
});
```

Now in my html view i need to use exampleVariable

like this

```
<div ng-controller="ChildController as child">
     <h1>{{child.exampleVariable}}</h1>
</div>
```

How can i get the value from parentcontroller to html view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Broadcast and On in the Controller-

```
app.controller('ParentController', function($scope) {
    var self = this;         
     $scope.$broadcast('exampleVariable', 'test');
});
```

and in child controller -

```
app.controller('ChildController', function($scope, $controller) {
var someScopeVariable = this;
$controller('ParentController', {$scope: someScopeVariable });
  console.log(someScopeVariable.exampleVariable) 

 $scope.$on('exampleVariable', function(event, data) {
 someScopeVariable.exampleVariable = data;
});

});
```

Comment: I need to modify the exampleVariable in the child controller. It is not possible if we write as you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

You can always use a service to share data between controllers.

- create a service

> ```
> app.service('myservice', function() {
>    var myVar; 
>
>    this.setMyVar = function(value){
>       this.myVar = value
>    }
>
>    this.getMyVar = function(){
>          return this.myVar;
>    }
> });
> ```

pass it as a dependency and you can have the value shared.

> ```
> app.controller('ParentController',['$scope', 'myservice', function($scope, myservice) {
>      $scope.exampleVariable = "test"; 
>      myservice.setMyVar("test");
> }]);
> ```

you can pass it to other controller as a dependency too and you can do a getMyVar there!!

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways you can achieve this.

```
1. Through $rootScope.
2. By Creating Service.
3. Inheriting parent controller to children controller.
```

2 & 3 are already provided in other answers. Follow this if you want to achieve it using `$rootScope`.

JS :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('ParentController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.exampleVariable = "test";
});

app.controller('ChildController', function($scope) {

});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
  Parent Controller : {{exampleVariable}}
  <hr/>
</div>
<div ng-controller="ChildController">
   Children Controller : {{exampleVariable}}
</div>
```

[DEMO LINK.](https://plnkr.co/edit/hBF78vrMjscveZ8sIFSc?p=preview)

**Note :** You can also override the scope variable in children controller by adding the below code in `ChildController` :

```
$scope.exampleVariable = "overriding...";
```